# How I can read the file on the everyday basis in pentaho in this format? "tcms_oneed_YYYYMMDD.txt"

Tags: etl, pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration, pentaho-cde

I want to read the file from FTP server to pentaho with this particular format.

tcms_oneed_YYYYMMDD.txt

YYYYMMDD is the sysdate.

Answer (score 0):

You pass the date in a parameter to the transformation and use the parameter when indicating the name of the file to read or you can calculate the file name in previous steps and check the box indicating to accept filenames from previous steps, indicating the name of the column with the filename.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use a get files and add a wildcard with regex to batch capture all files that are inside a directory.

PS: If you need to read one by one you can play inside a JOB and mark to read one line at a time, I hope that's what you need.

I'll leave a screenshot below of the demo of the test I did so you can view

**Wildcard**: tcms_oneed_\d{8}.*.txt

[Step - PRINT of Get files Pentaho](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IkMYD.png)